# Joining 3 tables and using SUM to calculate ratings of forum posts belonging to one thread

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, inner-join, where-clause

I'm doing a simple discussion board for my school project. I have these tables to store users, posts and ratings for those posts (I'll leave out columns and tables that are insignificant for this question.

```
+------------+
|    User    |
+------------+
|PK|  id_user|
+------------+
|    username|
| profile_pic|
+------------+   

+------------+
|    Post    |
+------------+
|PK|  id_post|
+------------+
|     id_user|
|   id_thread|
|     content|
| date_posted|
|     deleted|
+------------+ 

+------------+
|Post_ratings|
+------------+
|PK| id_voter|
|PK|  id_post|
+------------+
|      rating|
+------------+
```

What I want to do is select all rows from the `Post` table with a specific `id_thread`, join it with the `User` table to select the `username` and `profile_pic` of the poster of each post, and a sum of ratings given to each post, so the columns of the result should be `id_post`, `id_user`, `content`, `date_posted`, `deleted`, `username`, `profile_pic`, and `rating`.

I managed to come up only with this sloppy query:

```
SELECT * FROM Post p LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT id_user, username, profile_pic FROM User) u 
ON p.id_user = u.id_user LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT id_post redundant, SUM(rating) rating FROM Post_ratings) pr 
ON p.id_post = pr.redundant 
WHERE id_thread = 5 AND deleted = 0 
ORDER BY date_posted
```

This does return all posts belonging to one thread, but it shows post's ID twice (the `redundant` column) and displays SUM of *all* ratings across all threads in a row with the lowest `id_post`, shows `NULL` in other rows.

If anyone can help, thank you in advance.

Comment: @Strawberry I'll keep this in mind if I have more SQL query questions in the future. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a join to associate the users and the posts table, and a subquery to sum the ratings:

```
select p.*, u.username, u.profile_pic,
    (select sum(pr.rating) from post_ratings pr where pr.id_post = p.id_post) as rating
from posts p
inner join users u on u.id_user = p.id_user
where p.id_thread = 5 and p.deleted = 0
```

Of course, you can also use outer aggregation:

```
select p.*, u.username, u.profile_pic, sum(pr.rating) as rating
from posts p
inner join users u on u.id_user = p.id_user
inner join post_ratings pr on pr.id_post = p.id_post
where p.id_thread = 5 and p.deleted = 0
group by p.id_post, u.user_id
```

MySQL understand functionally-dependent columns, so it is sufficient to put the primary key of the posts and users table in the `group by` clause.